# Is it possible to create a view where the list of columns is picked up from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 to be specific

What I want to do is:

- **Table1** : 3 columns `C1,C2,C3` and any number of rows
- **Table2** : 1 column `col` and upto 3 rows

Each row in `Table2` contains `C1`, `C2` or `C3` (no duplicates)

I want to do something like

```
create view v1 on 
(
    select (select col from Table2) from Table1
)
```

So, if `Table2` contains `C1` and `C2`, the view that is created shows `C1` and `C2`

If `Table2` is updated with say `C3` added, and the query re executed, the view will now show `C1`, `C2` and `C3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution

Used the following method:

Create a stored procedure to make the required statement `create view v1 on (select C1,c2 from t2)` by using a cursor to iterate over each row and form the proper string.

Used this string in an exec() to create the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a view that does that.

But you can create dynamic SQL (ie: in a stored procedure) that would return the desired result.

```
 declare @s varchar(500)
 select @s = ''
 select @s = ', ' + col from table2

 declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

 select @sql = 'select ' + substring(@s, 2, len(@s)) + ' from table1'

 exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

If you really want to join against such a thing I see 2 possibilities:

- use dynamic sql to create the view just prior to using it. But because the view will be visible to other users as well (that might need the other version of it) this may not be a solution.
- use dynamic sql to create a temporary table, and use that. A temporary table will only be visible in the current connection

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
DECLARE @coll nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)
set @query = 'select '
DECLARE @colcursor CURSOR
SET @colcursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT col
FROM Table2
OPEN @colcursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @colcursor INTO @coll
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--PRINT @coll
set @query = @query + @coll  + ','
FETCH NEXT
FROM @colcursor INTO @coll
END
CLOSE @colcursor
DEALLOCATE @colcursor
set @query = left(@query,(len(@query)-1)) + 'from Table1'
print @query
exec(@query)
```